# hashset to remove duplicates from array Java

Tags: java, duplicates

I'm currently trying to get my java program to not print out duplicate laws in print out. The software is random picking to print out 1 to 3 laws but I don't want duplicates. I'm still kind of new to java and only have written a few programs so far. This is the most complicated one I've written so far.

Right now I want the software to run the random again if it finds a duplicate till there are no duplicates in the print. Is there anyway to do do this ?

```
/**
    *Seeds is a random number to pick which if statement will be used. 
    * telling the software how many laws to use during its random 
    * generation process
    * 
    */
    Random seeds = new Random(); 
    seed = seeds.nextInt(3) + 1; 

    if (seed == 1){


        /**Beginning of random law selection for universe. Must find way 
         *Must find way to get rid of duplicate answers 
         */
        final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
            "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law:" + Laws[index]);
    }

    else if (seed == 2) {

        final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
            "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index2 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law:" + Laws[index] + "," + Laws[index2]);

    }

    else {

        final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
            "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index2 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index3 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law: " + Laws[index] + "," + Laws[index2] + 
                    "," + Laws[index3]);

    }
```

Comment: less line of code, less problems, 3 declarations of the same String array is not good, declare it once at the top above all if else blocks

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of this problem is; you want to select values in a random order.  This way you won't get duplicates unless an element appears more than once.

```
List<String> laws = Arrays.asList("Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
        "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic");
Collections.shuffle(laws);
// select as many as you need
List<String> lawsSelected = laws.subList(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. You've 3 if conditions so take 3 boolean variables and associate one with each if and make it true when that if is executed.

```
Random seeds = new Random(); 
    seed = seeds.nextInt(3) + 1; 


boolean selected[] = new boolean[3];
selected[0] = selected[1] = selected[2] = false;//initially none of the if is executed

    if (seed == 1 && !selected[seed-1]){//checking if not previously selected and "seed-1" since array indexes are from 0 to n-1


        /**Beginning of random law selection for universe. Must find way 
         *Must find way to get rid of duplicate answers 
         */
        final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
            "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law:" + Laws[index]);
            selected[seed-1] = true;
    }

    else if (seed == 2 && !selected[seed-1]) {

        final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
            "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index2 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law:" + Laws[index] + "," + Laws[index2]);
            selected[seed-1] = true;
    }

    else if (!selected[seed-1]){

        final String[] Laws = {"Standard Physics", "Magic", "Mad Science", 
            "Psionics", "Substandard Physics","Exotic"};
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index2 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            int index3 = random.nextInt(Laws.length);
            System.out.println("Law: " + Laws[index] + "," + Laws[index2] + 
                    "," + Laws[index3]);
        selected[seed-1] = true;
    }
```